# Много-много Ajax запросов ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Можно ли отправить сразу несколько Ajax запросов, обработать на сервере каждый, затем получить результат от сервера (например дата завершения обработки для каждого)?

Answer (score 1):

Сколько не искал, пришёл к одному выводу - нельзя.

P.S. Как решение этой проблемы написал на JavaScript свой AjaxManager, который хранит очередь запросов и по-одному обрабатывает их.